# Twilio: Unable to send Message using Test Credentials

Tags: c#, twilio

I signed up for a new twilio account. Got twilio test-credentials & then used Twilio Rest Api from nuget package to send sms in c#. The problem i am getting is it gives invalid phone number.

I dont know where to search because the documentation is confusing.

This is what i have done so far:

```
var body = "This is a test message.";
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccSid, AuthToken);
var msg = twilio.SendMessage("+13184794329", "+918871022168", body);
```

Please help me. Thanx in Advance.

Comment: Show what you have so far. "[I]f your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. [...] Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem."  [SOURCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have edited my question according to your comment. Please feel free to ask.

Comment: Maybe you should check the phone number if it says it's invalid.

Comment: But twilio only provided this number for testing.

Comment: `+1318479432` is `+1 318-479-432`  Does the number you're sending have 3+7 digits?  Also see: [Formatting International Phone Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/how-do-i-format-phone-numbers-to-work-internationally)

Comment: Also: https://www.twilio.com/lookup  you can test the number to see if their API can validate the number

Comment: @theB : Just edited my question, thanx for noticing the mistake. +1 from my side.

Comment: Thanx a lot all for helping & giving usefull suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Test credentials are only used to simulate sending a message, but no actual messages are sent. See more information about them [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials).

If you want your message to be sent you need to use your live credentials, which you can find on your [Account Page](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/voice) by expanding the **Show API Credentials** link.

As for getting invalid phone number, I just checked the number you provided, and it seems to be a valid "From" number, but I think you forgot to add the +1 to it initially.

If you use the correct credentials, you should be able to send SMS messages, but do keep in mind that mobile numbers in India (as the one you're using) have limitations during the day as you can see [in this link](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices).

Hope this helps you

Comment: I used the Api credentials you said. But the SMS is not going but this time the api responded with success unlike previous times. Secondly the usage tab is showing charges so what are these charges if i am in testing phase.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshithere any SMS message you successfully send will be charged. If you want to stop it from incurring charges, you can use the Test credentials. You will get the same experience,  but the messages won't be delivered.

Comment: Ok Thanx a lot for helping.